# If $\mu(E)\geqslant 0$ is it true that $E\in \mathfrak{M}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a mesure space. Let $E$ such that $\mu(E)\geqslant 0$. Can we conclude that $E\in \mathfrak{M}$?

I think YES because $\mu$ is the set function with domain $\mathfrak{M}$. Since $\mu(E)$ is defined then $E\in \mathfrak{M}$. Am I right?

Comment: It only makes sense to talk about $\mu(E)$ when $E\in \mathfrak{M}$, so yes.

Comment: If $\mu(E)<0$, it also follows that $E\in \mathfrak{M}$.

Comment: @Batominovski, why? Can you explain it please?

Comment: Your question is essentially this: If $x$ is in the domain of $f$, is $x$ in the domain of $f?$

Comment: @RFZ  See zhw's comment for the explanation.